# How to configure fields in Django forms.Form?

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Django and web dev and having difficulty configuring the fields in Django forms.Form so that they come out correctly. Below is my code:

Even if I adjust my attrs rows and cols in `forms.Textarea` it doesn't make any difference. Also, it doesn't seem to matter what I put in CSS the output is still the same.

```
class NewPageForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(label="Title", max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput)
    content = forms.CharField(label="Content", widget=forms.Textarea(attrs{"rows":3,"cols":10}))
```

My html:

```
{% block body %}    
    <div class="form">
        <form action="{% url 'create' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input type = submit>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

What it looks like:

[image: screenshot]

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
content = forms.CharField(label=False, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 3}))
```

or even add a CSS class to customize it:

```
content = forms.CharField(label=False, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': 3}))
```

Comment: Can you please show what I would do in CSS? It doesn't matter if I change the rows in attrs, making no difference.

Comment: In my case, I use the bootstrap css framework, however, your problem is may you should use "attrs={}" not "attrs{} Check out my example: https://github.com/infantiablue/tweeter/blob/main/network/forms.py

Comment: Oh, and you may need to reset the CSS, some default settings could override the django setting on the form

Comment: How do I reset the CSS? Maybe that's why no matter what update I do in CSS, nothing changes.

Comment: You may try this https://gist.github.com/DavidWells/18e73022e723037a50d6 but I recommend you to use a CSS framework instead.

Comment: If I did ```widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})``` would my css be div.form.form-control{...}?

Comment: Its HTML output will be <textarea name="text" cols="40" rows="3" class="form-control" maxlength="300" required="" id="id_text" spellcheck="false"></textarea>